# How to disable the display from a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, printf, display

A function `gradient()` is writed by some developer, and I try to call it in my `main()` function. However, inside the `gradient()`, it will print some message as following:

```
Total time is 0.045420 [s] (excludes statsfun) iter                cost val     grad. norm
0   -2.1794659039050758e+08 4.47344788e+08
1   -5.9276958454539728e+08 3.03276019e+08
2   -6.3078232706850171e+08 1.47674763e+08
3   -6.3981329944849074e+08 7.63431416e+07
4   -6.4251920114089453e+08 5.53428795e+07
5   -6.4558893912953174e+08 5.07800110e+07
```

How to disable display those message from the `gradient()` ?

Comment: By editing `gradient` or, if the developer was nice, by setting whatever flag hides the command window output. Not really possible to answer without knowing how `gradient` is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of editing `gradient.m`, you can always fall back on [`evalc`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) as a last resort. So, instead of writing

```
[out1, out2] = gradient(in);
```

You'd write

```
[~, out1, out2] = evalc('gradient(in);');
```